# Generate Client Cert For TLS Asterisk

Tags: sip, asterisk, voip

I'm trying to enable TLS b/w my asterisk powered voip server and clients(android devices), following the guidelines mentioned [here](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Secure+Calling+Tutorial). For generating client certs

```
./ast_tls_cert -m client -c /etc/asterisk/keys/ca.crt -k /etc/asterisk/keys/ca.key -C phone1.mycompany.com -O "My Super Company" -d /etc/asterisk/keys -o malcolm
```

> "The "-C" option, since we're defining a client this time, is used to define the hostname or >IP address of our SIP phone"

i dont want to tightly couple the user with anyone IP address, how can i workaround this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Address just added to certificate

After that is client task check address same or differ

Most clients ignore that address at all, not check anything.

Comment: sry i didnt understand, are you saying i should leave the filed empty?

Comment: or you are saying i should enter the ip of the client, that will not make any difference?

Comment: I am saying that soft usually ignore that info in certificate. You can put anything

Comment: can you have a look at this question, http://stackoverflow.com/q/26729200/1679410